# Send Firebase Push Notification using Node Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to use NodeJS module to send Push Notification.

Looking at 'node-sender' module and do not see option to send to Browser (for testing):

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sender
```

What Node Module do you recommend for sending PN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [node-pushnotifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications) a shot. They have a very detailed documentation and quite fairly used.

Comment: Does this module (node-pushnotifications) support http2 (https://onesignal.com/blog/apple-just-released-http2-support-for-their-push-notification-api/) ?